# Theorem 8.2 in Billingsley "Convergence of Probability Measures" FIRST EDITION

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

I'm looking for Theorem 8.2 in Billingsley's book. I can only find the second edition, but I'm looking for the Theorem 8.2 from the **first** edition. If I'm correct it has got something to do with tightness of probability measures of random functions in $C(\mathbb{R})$. Does anyone have the first edition of this book laying around?

I can not find it anywhere! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but this is theorem 8.2 in the first edition.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is it!